# Not able to fetch correct values against checkboxes

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, checkbox

I have a form that has a value of name and age against each checkbox as shown in the image.

[image]

The issue is that even when a checkbox is not selected but the input values against that checkbox is filled then it goes to the backend. I want that if the checkbox is not selected then even if the input text is filled the values of name and age against it should not go to the backend
The value of age and name should only go to the backend if the checkbox is selected

```
<form method="POST" action="savedata.php">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input name="checkbox_value[]" type="checkbox" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" >
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="child_name[]" placeholder="Name" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php echo $child_name; ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="age" name="child_age[]" class="child-age" placeholder="Age" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php echo $child_age; ?>">
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

When fetching the data at savedata.php using

```
print_r($_POST);
```

I get the following array

```
Array
(
    [checkbox_value] => Array
        (
            [0] => on
            [1] => on
        )
    [child_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => child 1
            [1] => child 2
            [2] => child 3
        )
    [child_age] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 10
        )
)
```

The resulting array that I want is

```
Array
(
    [checkbox_value] => Array
        (
            [0] => on
            [1] => on
        )
    [child_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => child 1
            [1] => child 2
        )
    [child_age] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 6
        )
)
```

Would appreciate if anyone can tell how to solve this issue and also if this is not possible then is it possible to put a check that if the checkbox_value has 2 values then i can select 2 values from child_name and child_age array

Comment: You cannot do that, input have no in-between linking. This said, you can get only the value of `child_name` and `child_age` that are checked, by some simple php processing.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε is there a possibilty of creating a in-between linking

Comment: Not in HTML, you might want to do this in JS. but then you can just blank the value of the input when you uncheck the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You can process the answer by testing the activation or not for the checkbox like this:

`if (isset([checkbox_value][0]))`

Then, you can put the data in a new array with the structure you want (i.e. your second example)